# How to recover after non-active storage engine failure after unclean shutdown on standalone MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

There are a few SO questions tangentially related. But none quite as simple as this solution:

I was running a standalone mongodb single instance on Mac OSX for development purposes.

Mac crashed...

On restarting the mongo, I could see Mongo trying to recover (`mongod.lock` file detected) and restart.

(In the past, I would just blow away all of my local dev database folder and start over. Kind of a bummer. But this time I decided to dig a little deeper.)

The key thing to note in the console output is that it found *"files created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'."* Essentially overriding the config setting for wiredTiger.

:-O

My console (edited for brevity):

```
db version v3.2.10
git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
allocator: system
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
options: { ...storage: { dbPath: "/Users/jon/databases/mongodb", directoryPerDB: true, journal: { enabled: true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 4 } } }, ... }
Detected data files in /Users/jon/databases/mongodb created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
Detected unclean shutdown - /Users/jon/databases/mongodb/mongod.lock is not empty.
journal dir=/Users/jon/databases/mongodb/journal
recover begin
info no lsn file in journal/ directory
recover lsn: 0
recover /Users/jon/databases/mongodb/journal/j._0
recover cleaning up
removeJournalFiles
recover done
Durability thread started
Journal writer thread started
```

But I received this warning:

```
Detected configuration for non-active storage engine wiredTiger when current storage engine is mmapv1
```

And it ends badly:

```
***aborting after invariant() failure
...
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

### A SOLUTION

Admittedly, this is a sticky situation to find yourself in.

I backed up my entire local folder, just so I could try other approaches...

I looked over the directory where I store the database files and **purged older folders** that truly were not needed. But this may not have been the reason things worked.

I also ran a repair (it could require removal of the journal file depending on your situation):

```
mongod --dbpath /Users/jon/databases/mongodb --repair
```

Upon restarting mongo, everything was back to normal.